# Getting remote server file seperator(ie. "/" in linux or "\" in windows) using java

Tags: java

I am running a java application on system A and using that java application on system B. How to get the file seperator string on system B(remote one).

am connecting to remote server with sftp or ssh( usig java jsch libs).

Comment: How are you connecting to B?

Comment: Why? '/' works in Java filenames on all systems.

Comment: Why don't you send a message from the client to the server to ask for the file separator (or use `/` as EJP suggested)

Comment: am connecting with sftp or ssh another option

Comment: I feel littlebit lost. Where is your "java question" here exactly?
Connection layer is not relevant, if you are using Java on both sides.On 'A' you have to "ASK" 'B' to provide file separator just like I have posted in my anwser below

Comment: @Antoniossss,i mean using java programming lanuage how to get the remote system file seperator value while connecting with ssh or sftp

Comment: If you are really need something like that (IMHO It is not really sane) than you can store `File.separator` into some kind of common file and download in using SSH or SFTP. Still sounds like pleanty of work. If you are using cliend-server application that i really suggest to use RMI or CORBA. It will make your work faster, and your code will be simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On target system use `File.separator`. It holds platform dependent separator for path (`/` linux and `\` in windows)
Eg. If you are using RMI you can declare remote method like

```
public char getFileSeparator() throws RemoteException{
    return File.separator;
}
```

Comment: can u please give some examples.(code)

Comment: Read the code example, than start downvoling. Author didnt mention how he is "connected" to remote host. My suggestion is to create service for providing such information via RMI (or any kind of service he is using). Moreover i have pointed out to use `File.separator` **ON TARGETED SYSTEM** not locally.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just use "/"?  That works on Windows too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get from [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) like below,

```
System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

Comment: but need to get the remote system property ,and i don't how how to get that

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should always use `File.separator` instead of hardcoded separators like "/" or "\" in your Java code.